# Cannot save/update selectList field

Tags: visualforce, selectlist

In my controller I have a static list of select options:

```
public List<SelectOption> getVesselTypeList() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<Selectoption>();
    options.add(new selectOption('OTH', 'SOLAS Vessel'));
    options.add(new selectOption('NONM', 'Non-SOLAS Vessel'));
    options.add(new selectOption('NOT', 'Not a Vessel'));
    return options;
}
```

Selected options value should be stored in custom field VesselType__c. Field is of type text with length of 8 characters which is enough for all values:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!ZInstallation__c.VesselType__c}" size="1"> 
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!VesselTypeList}" /> 
</apex:selectList>
```

Produced HTML:

```
<select name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:j_id11:j_id57:j_id59" size="1">
    <option value="OTH">SOLAS Vessel</option>
    <option value="NONM">Non-SOLAS Vessel</option>
    <option value="NOT">Not a Vessel</option>
</select>
```

On update/insert I get this error message:

> Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a8qO0000000CbIEIA0;
>   first error: STRING_TOO_LONG, Type of ship:: data value too large:
>   SOLAS Vessel (max length=8): [VesselType__c] Error is in expression
>   '{!submit}' in component  in page z_installation:
>   Class.ZInstallationController.submit: line 414, column 1

It seems as if Salesforce stores the options text in field VesselType__c and not its value. How can I save the options value in my text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a String attribute like `selectedValue` in Controller and during save use that value.

Visualforce

```
String selectedValue {get;set;}

<apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}" size="1"> 
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!VesselTypeList}" /> 
</apex:selectList>
```

**Controller** during update or insert

```
ZInstallation__c.VesselType__c = selectedValue;
```

In case you need to assign value on edit mode and display to the user

```
selectedValue = ZInstallation__c.VesselType__c;
```

Comment: thanks, that prevents the error. But how I get the selectedValue on submit exactly? Your example seems to reset the old selected value on update.

Comment: Ok, now it works